# Snowflake Stored procedure Copy into Temporary table

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, java-stored-procedures, snowsql

Question is related to Snowflake and Snowsql. That said I'm trying to within a stored proc create a temp table and then 'copy into' this temp table from azure blob storage.
I'm manually executed the snow sql statements and they work fine.
Statement 1:`CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE DB.TABLES.LINE_DETAILS_INCREMENTAL LIKE DB.TABLES.LINE_DETAILS;`

Statement 2:

```
COPY INTO DB.TABLES.LINE_DETAILS_INCREMENTAL FROM (SELECT * FROM @DB.BASE.Azure/S/LINE_DETAILS_INCREMENTAL )
force = false file_format = (type = csv field_delimiter = '|' encoding = 'Windows 1252' skip_header = 0);
```

But when I encapsulate this into a stored proc and try to run it it gives error:-
"JavaScript compilation error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier in SP_DELETE_LINE_DETAILS at ' var insert_clause = 'COPY INTO DB.TABLES.LINE_DETAILS_INCREMENTAL FROM (SELECT * FROM @Feeds_DB.BASE.Azure/S/LINE_DETAILS_INCREMENTAL ) force = true file_format = (type = csv field_delimiter = '|' encoding = 'Windows1252' skip_header = 0) On_error = continue;'' position 288 ".
Code of the stored proc is:-

```
CREATE or replace procedure  "DB"."TABLES"."SP_DELETE_INSERT_3DAYS_INTO_LINE_DETAILS"()
returns varchar(1000)
language javascript
as
$$
try{
var create_clause = 'CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE DB.TABLES.LINE_DETAILS_INCREMENTAL LIKE DB.TABLES.PS_TRANSACTION_LINE_DETAILS;'
        var create_stmt  = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText: create_clause});   
        var create_res = create_stmt.execute();
        
        var insert_clause = 'COPY INTO DB.TABLES.LINE_DETAILS_INCREMENTAL FROM (SELECT * FROM @Tableau_Feeds_DB.BASE_TABLES.JDAStagingAzure/POS/PS_TRANSACTION_LINE_DETAILS_INCREMENTAL ) force = true file_format = (type = csv field_delimiter = '|' encoding = 'Windows1252' skip_header = 0) On_error = continue;'
        var insert_stmt = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText: insert_clause});  
        var insert_res = insert_stmt.execute();
        var select_clause = 'select distinct TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(CREATE_DATE)) as CREATE_DATE from DB.TABLES.LINE_DETAILS_INCREMENTAL order by CREATE_DATE';
        var select_stmt  = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText: select_clause});
        var select_res   = select_stmt.execute();
 while (select_res.next()) 
            {
            date_ip = select_res.getColumnValue(1);
            var desc_user_sql  = `delete from DB.TABLES.LINE_DETAILS where TO_DATE(CREATE_DATE) = :1;`
            var desc_user_stmt  = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText: desc_user_sql, binds: [date_ip]});

            var desc_user_sql2  = `INSERT INTO DB.TABLES.PS_TRANSACTION_LINE_DETAILS select * from DB.TABLES.PS_TRANSACTION_LINE_DETAILS_INCREMENTAL where TO_DATE(CREATE_DATE) = :1;`
            var desc_user_stmt2  = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText: desc_user_sql2, binds: [date_ip]});

            try{
                       desc_user_stmt.execute();
                       desc_user_stmt2.execute();
                  }
               catch(err)
                  {
                   return "Error inserting records: " +err;
                  }              
            }
            return "Data has been insert in success!";
        }
        
        catch(err){
               return "Error whileselecting Roles : " +err;
        }
return 0;
$$
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue you have here is that you're using single quote marks both to start/end your string, and within the string itself.

For example, you have the following phrase in your string:

```
encoding = 'Windows1252'
```

I would suggest escaping the additional quotation marks with a backslash, like so:

```
encoding = \'Windows1252\'
```

Do this for all additional quotation marks and you should be fine.

Let me know if you still face issues after!

Comment: Good to know @Chris . Thank you. 'Iqra Ijaz' above answer did the trick. BUT I'm sure the escape characters are good to have/know for future cases. I have bunch of migration proc's from SQL server to snowflake.

Comment: You're welcome @junketsu. Changing the string identifier to a grave accent ` definitely does the job as well, just keep in mind that if your code contains grave accents within any strings, those will also need to be escaped. 

TLDR; Always escape any characters that may interrupt your string early

Answer (score 1):

Try changing single quotes as below

```
var insert_clause = `COPY INTO DB.TABLES.LINE_DETAILS_INCREMENTAL FROM (SELECT * FROM @Tableau_Feeds_DB.BASE_TABLES.JDAStagingAzure/POS/PS_TRANSACTION_LINE_DETAILS_INCREMENTAL ) force = true file_format = (type = csv field_delimiter = '|' encoding = 'Windows1252' skip_header = 0) On_error = continue;`
```

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/stored-procedures-usage.html#line-continuation